# Accelerometer based movement

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Now woking on game that uses accelerometer to move player sprite left and right.
I used this tutorial: [COCOS2D_ACCELEROMETER_MOVEMENT](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:using_accelerometer_for_sprite_movement)
This works only sometime….some time not move..How can I resolve this problem?
Here is my sample: [See this Sample](http://www.4shared.com/zip/BUJJedIy/testAcc.html)
Thanks for reading this…what's wrong with my code ? Is there any other way?

Here is my code:

```
#define kHeroMovementAction 1
#define kPlayerSpeed 500
- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    // use the running scene to grab the appropriate game layer by it's tag

    // grab the player sprite from that layer using it's tag
    CCSprite *playerSprite = mPlayer;
    float destX, destY;
    BOOL shouldMove = NO;

    float currentX = playerSprite.position.x;
    float currentY = playerSprite.position.y;

    if(acceleration.x > 0.25) {  // tilting the device upwards
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else if (acceleration.x < -0.25) {  // tilting the device downwards
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else 

        if(acceleration.y < -0.25) {  // tilting the device to the right
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else if (acceleration.y > 0.25) {  // tilting the device to the left
        destX = currentX - (acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
        destY = currentY + (acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
        shouldMove = YES;
    } else {
        destX = currentX;
        destY = currentY;
    }

    if(shouldMove) 
    {
        CGSize wins = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        // ensure we aren't moving out of bounds     
        if(destX < 30 || destX > wins.width - 30 || destY < 30 || destY > wins.height - 100) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            CCAction *action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position: CGPointMake(destX, playerSprite.position.y)];
            [playerSprite stopActionByTag:kHeroMovementAction];
            [action setTag:kHeroMovementAction];
            [playerSprite runAction:action];
        }
    } else {
        // should stop
        [playerSprite stopActionByTag:kHeroMovementAction];
    }

}
```

**Updates: Here is [best way to do this.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/accelerometer-to-move-player-left-and-right/33427#33427)**

Comment: I got right solution here in this place:   http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/accelerometer-to-move-player-left-and-right/33427#33427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at Ray Wenderlich's scrolling tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6804/how-to-make-a-multi-directional-scrolling-shooter-part-1#Adding_Accelerometer_Support)

His accelerometer part is near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that "Tanks" sample in Ray Wenderlich's tutorial also not working all the time in my device..oh: iPod Touch 4G,iOS5....in that movement is random direction.but I need to use for just left and right device tilt.

Comment: what you would need to do then is just implement the Y direction acceleration

Comment: I tried that also..but it stops some time...anyway I followed this alternate way: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/accelerometer-to-move-player-left-and-right/33427#33427